# Cardinality of the set of an atmost countable number of functions

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

If $\beth_0$ is the cardinality of the natural numbers, $\beth_1$ the cardinality of the continuum, $\beth_2$ the cardinality of the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of Real numbers, then is the cardinality of the set of sequences of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $\beth_1$?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you mean $\beth_0$ and $\beth_1$ by Beth null and Beth one?

Comment: @f.nasim: Yes, that what these mean.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you are asking what is $(\beth_2)^{\beth_0}$, which is the cardinality of the set $\left(\Bbb{R^R}\right)^\Bbb N$.

This is easier to think of in terms of repeated exponentiation, and in terms of $\aleph$'s. Remember $\aleph_0=\beth_0$.

$$(\beth_2)^{\beth_0}=\left(2^{2^{\aleph_0}}\right)^{\aleph_0}=2^{2^{\aleph_0}\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}=\beth_2.$$

Generally, if a set has size $\kappa$, then $\kappa\leq\kappa^\lambda$, whenever $\lambda>0$. So if we start with a set of size $\beth_2$ it is impossible that by raising it to the power of $\aleph_0$ we get $\beth_1$.

Comment: Firstly,thanks !
I myself am not quite sure if what I'm asking translates into $(\beth_2)^{ \beth_0}$.Intuitively,it seems conflicting to me that $\beth_2$ can be used to represent the cardinality of both:The set of all functions from R to R and the set of only an atmost countable number of function from R to R.I feel so,because the former represents an uncountable set of functions,where each function maps onto an uncountable set($\mathbb{R}$),whereas the latter represents a countable number of functions,where each function maps onto an uncountable set($\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand what does it mean "at most countable number of function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$". Do you mean sets of functions which are at most countable? If so, then this is the correct calculation. Note, for example that $\beth_1$ is both the cardinality of the real numbers, but also the cardinality of sequences of real numbers.

Comment: By "at most countable number of function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$", I meant the cardinality of the set of sequences of functions,$f_{n}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
I was trying to imply that for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$,the sequence $f_{n}(c)$ is countable,but for $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$,the sequence is uncountable.This,however,is different from the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.My question,simply rephrased,is are the cardinalities of above two mentioned sets the same ?

Comment: Which one of the two: $$1.\left\{\langle f_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\rangle\mid f_n\colon\Bbb{R\to R}\right\}$$ $$2.\left\{f\mid f\colon\Bbb{N\to R}\right\}$$

Comment: :The first one.

Comment: So I understood you the first time, and there is no need to edit my answer.